# PHP application using Windows Authentication to a MSSQL server

Tags: php, sql-server, single-sign-on, windows-authentication

This is not a new topic, but the information I find is always covering only a bit or not exactly what I would need. Here's the "issue"

I'm building a web application, on a Debian / Apache / PHP host.
The web server is NOT in our Active Directory, nor will it be.

Now the web application would need to query Microsoft SQL servers to gather the information to display and so on. 
Now, I've installed the Microsoft SQL drivers (version 17) and try to connect. This gives errors because we only allow windows authentication and not directly SQL authentication. 
This is where the problem starts. I cannot find any proper documentation on how to get this working. It seems that if you connect without UID and PWD, it tries to logon with the UID owner of the process. This is in this case the APACHE user...which is an account on the Linux server, not known in the Active Directory /Domain. I can't have the Apache server run as a windows account, since that will impact other domains and applications running on that web server.  Meaning I'm stuck....
So the questions are basically:

- Is there really no proper solution to implement Windows Authentication to MSSQL with PHP (so without work arounds and so on?
- Is there any site where this is explained in detail or any developed module for PHP, maybe with javascript or anything.

I can't believe this is not possible, but can't find any working solutions...
Thanks in advance everyone for taking the time to read and reply!

Comment: *"The web server is NOT in our Active Directory, nor will it be."* Then how do you suppose you're doing to use said Active Directory to authenticate? Impersonation, or the service running under the account it needs to use, needs the host to be in the AD. Otherwise it can't authenticate the user account, and then pass its credentials.

Comment: _"It seems that if you connect without UID and PWD, it tries to logon with the UID owner of the process"_ ...yep that's pretty much it. So, Windows Auth is not going to work here. If you're not logged in as a Windows/AD user, you can't expect to be authenticated as one. QED. You need to get a SQL login set up specifically for your app. _"we only allow windows authentication"_ sounds like a pretty arbitrary rule made up by someone who likes "neatness" in their bureaucracy more than they like working software. If they won't budge, you'll have to move the PHP application to a Windows server.

Comment: I was a bit afraid of such answer ;-) So there is no way to force the webserver to use existing Windows / AD tokens, or credentials to send when connection is made?

Comment: Just to note, you don't *have* to move the PHP application to a Windows Server, you can add Linux hosts to a Windows Domain and then authenticate with Kerboros. *"So there is no way to force the webserver to use existing Windows / AD tokens, or credentials to send when connection is made?"* yes, add the host to the domain so it can authenticate said AD Users.

Comment: That's true. To add to Larnu's suggestion, if you're worried (as you stated in the question) about the impact of this on other applications on the server, then either run a separate instance of Apache (or another webserver) running under a different, AD-recognised identity (Linux admins might even know a better way to do this) to host your PHP app, or just make another server (VMs are easy to create) for this app and join it to the domain.

Comment: But to answer your question more specifically, no there is no way to force the webserver to use existing Windows AD credentials which are not the credentials of the account it's running under. You can't send SQL Server an arbitrary Windows username & password, if that's what you're thinking. SQL always tries to read the identity of the account which is connecting to it, and then talks to Active Directory to verify the status of that account. The password etc is never sent directly in the connection, when using Windows Auth with SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks guys so far! So if I read well, Kerberos seems the closest solution here? But would require the webserver to have an AD user account....Is there an up to date guide on this available that someone knows of?

Comment: I'm not a sysadmin so I don't have something specific to recommend. But just google "join linux to active directory" and you get lots of articles to get you started. This is something you'll probably want your Ops people to do, it's not really a Dev job.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/how-to-connect-using-windows-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16